Why does Angular change error response in production?
I am not able to identify the root cause behind error response change. In my local I see following error message.

based on this status code I am writing my logic.
However, in production the error response is completely different

What is it trying to say? How do I fix this?
 getScenarioByScenarioId(ID) {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.basePath + `scenario/` + ID, {
      headers: this.getHeader(),
    });
  }
 getHeader() {
    return {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      accept: 'application/json'
    }
  }

http.interceptor code
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        if (request.url.includes('configurations') || request.url.includes('gisMixedContent')) {
            return from(this.handleAccess(request, next));
        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }

    private async handleAccess(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Promise<HttpEvent<any>> {

        const getAuthToken = await this.authService.getAuthToken().toPromise();
        const changedReq = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${getAuthToken}`
            }

        });

        return next.handle(changedReq).toPromise();
    }
}


for production build, set sourceMap to true, then place a debugger on throwUnobservableError.js and check the stack trace!

Yes, It is already set to true

in angular.json, there is a property, aot set it to false that might fix it,  but the proper way to fix this, is to debug the error in chrome debugger. If not, you need to manually comment code to identify which component causes the issue

You haven't wrapped this line const getAuthToken = await this.authService.getAuthToken().toPromise(); in try / catch. I would advise doing that to help debug the problem.

It would simplify the code if you didn't return a promise from handleAccess, then you wouldn't have to convert it back into an Observable on the intercept. Simplifying the code could help you debug this further.

You are right , interceptor is not able to handle the error. I tried to handle it but no success
return next.handle(changedReq).pipe(
catchError(error => {
if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
console.log('error status = ', error);
}
return throwError(error);
})
).toPromise();

I also tried remove toPromise() but I think it is expecting it to be promise Type 'Observable<HttpEvent>' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent'.ts(2322)

you can use .pipe's "catchError" in rjxs to intercept the errors: https://v17.angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt6#error-handling  Then make sure getAuthToken fails gracefully.
